# Symfony - How to upload large files to onedrive?

Tags: php, symfony, curl, onedrive

Hello, how are you?
Currently, I am building a symfony project(symfony 5.4).
I am going to write a standalone upload script to upload backup files(.zip files) automatically to OneDrive.
And the files are up to 5 GB.
But I am not sure what should I start from and how to implement it.
If someone who has experiences in it, please let me know the way.
Any comment or suggestion will welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of open source, whenever you need a specific requirement, most probably someone else has published a library for it. You are in luck because there is already https://github.com/krizalys/onedrive-php-sdk. You can either use that library or reverse engineer from the source code to implement into your Symfony code base.